# Segmentation fault when non-capitalized input is given due to toupper used in a condition which inturn is used inside a for loop [C]

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to write a program for the course CS50, where I need to get the initial of full names of people (and make sure it's all capitalized).

Therefore, I ended up writing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
    //Asks user for input and checks for it's length
    printf("What's your name?\n");
    string full_name = get_string();
    int name_length = strlen(full_name);
    //Program to select the intitials of each word
    for(int i=0; i<name_length; i++)
    {
        char selectedchar = full_name[i]; //determines the currently selected character from the string on the basis of how many times the loop has run
        if(selectedchar != ' ')          //Makes the program ignore any spaces before the name
        {
            if(selectedchar>='A' && selectedchar<='z')
            {
                printf("%c", toupper(full_name[i]));
            }    
            else
            {
                printf("ERROR: INVALID INITIALS. (Check the characters used.)");
                return 1;
            }
        }

        //To skip printing of non-initials
        while(selectedchar != ' ')  
        {
            i++;
            selectedchar=full_name[i];
        }

        if(i>=name_length)       //print a linebreak on the end of each run
        {    
            printf("\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, whenver I input something, I get a segment fault. E:

**Input** Damien Chazelle **Result:** DCSegmentation fault (and line break)

**Input** Dam!en Chazelle **Result:** DCSegmentation fault (and line break)

**Input** Damien          **Result:** DSegmentation fault (and line break)

**Input** !Damien         **Result:** Segmentation fault  (and line break)

Now, I am a beginner! I have absolutely no idea of what's causing the problem or how to properly write this question. (Please pardon me for that!)

Comment: Your `while` loop can easily go out of bounds.

Comment: put the `if`condition into the `while` loop. Otherwise your while loop runs into infinity after the last space character and into the seg fault.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I solved it with the help of all of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while`-loop that shall set the pointer to the next blank will run out of bounds every time when a space is not the last character in the string:

```
    while(selectedchar != ' ')  
    {
        i++;
        selectedchar=full_name[i];
    }
```

Suppose a string like `"Damien Chazelle"`, and suppose that `i` points to character `C`: Then, as the string does not contain any more space from this position onwards, `i` will run out of bounds of the string. Note that string termination character `'\0'` is not equal `' '`, so the loop will step over.

Without interpreting the rest of your code to much, write

```
while(i < name_length && selectedchar != ' ')
```

instead.

Comment: WOW! I did know about the string terminator (\0) not being equivalent to space but rather just to itself, yet somehow I just forgot it when writing!

It amazes me how such a detail was left behind by me! (Maybe, it's just because I'm a newb)


Well, Thank you all! You helped me a lot!